# Some question on Boot2docker setup for build and run

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, bioinformatics, boot2docker

I’m a fresh beginner on bioinformatics. Recently, I start learning it with the book named “Bioinformatics with Python Cookbook (by Antao, Tiago)”. I met some issues while setting up Docker for Linux. Please see below for the issues:

1. I was trying to set up the Docker files following the author’s instruction, but I found some files were “failed to download”. 
   docker build -t bio
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiagoantao/bioinf-python/master/docker/2/Dockerfile
2. Then I still went ahead set up the container following the instruction: 
   “Now, you are ready to run the container, as follows: docker run -ti -p 9875:9875 -v YOUR_DIRECTORY:/data bio”

I typed as docker run -ti -p 9875:9875 -v C:/Users/guangliang/Desktop/Bioinformation/data bio

However, it gave me an error saying “Unable to find image “bio:latest” locally”.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on this? My thought could be the first step I missed downloading some files for setting the Dockers, but I am not sure if I can fetch these files. 
Thank you so much for any comments!

Best regards
Johnny

I tried downloading the docker files a few time, but the error still appears

docker build -t bio
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiagoantao/bioinf-python/master/docker/2/Dockerfile

docker run -ti -p 9875:9875 -v C:/Users/guangliang/Desktop/Bioinformation/data bio

In the first issue, I found some files were “failed to download”.
In the 2nd issue, an error saying “Unable to find image “bio:latest” locally”. appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a couple of problems:

1) It looks you do not download that docker file and build required docker image locally

2) You are getting that error about not finding image locally because of previous problem

So, you should do like this:

1) Download that Dockerfile (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiagoantao/bioinf-python/master/docker/2/Dockerfile). If you cant download that file for some reason, just open it at the git, select all content, copy, than in some folder on your computer make a new file, name it "Dockerfile" and paste the content.

2) Build locally image - go to the folder you download that dockerfile and execute following command:

```
docker build -t bio .
```

3)Run your container with docker run ... command

Comment: Thanks a lot, nick79. Yes, I also contacted the author and got the same answer. Also, I was reading the first edition book, which is no longer supported. The script from the second edition works great. I'm downloading the files now.

Comment: Glad to help you.